# Dart extract host from URL string

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, url

Supposing that I have the following URL as a String;

```dart
String urlSource = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/';
```

I want to extract the main page name from this url String; 'wikipedia', removing *https://* , *www* , *.com* , *.org* part from the url.

What is the best way to extract this? In case of **RegExp**, what regular expression do I have to use?

Comment: "wikipedia" is not a page name, it's a 2nd level domain. Anyways, `[^\.]+(?=\.[^\.]+$)` would work.

Comment: As noted below, it's better to use a pre-existing bit of code to handle the parsing for you.  Two lessons here: 1) Not every problem involving strings needs a regex, and 2) If the problem is one that other people are likely to have had, look for existing code that does it for you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You do **not need** to make use of [`RegExp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) in this case.

Dart has a premade class for parsing URLs:

### [`Uri`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Uri-class.html)

What you want to achieve is quite simple using that API:

```dart
final urlSource = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/';

final uri = Uri.parse(urlSource);
uri.host; // www.wikipedia.org
```

The [`Uri.host` property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Uri/host.html) will give you `www.wikipedia.org`. From there, you should easily be able to extract `wikipedia`.

`Uri.host` will also remove the *whole path*, i.e. anything after the `/` after the host.

#### Extracting the second-level domain

If you want to get the [second-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain), i.e. `wikipedia` from the host, you could just do `uri.host.split('.')[uri.host.split('.').length - 2]`.

However, note that this is not fail-safe because you might have subdomains or not (e.g. `www`) and the top-level domain might also be made up of multiple parts. For example, `co.uk` uses `co` as the second-level domain.

Comment: OP didn't ask about extracting the host.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I added an explanation - retrieving the second-level domain is actually not strictly always possible w/o a map of all top-level domains. Therefore, my simple example should do. However, it is really trivial from there..

Comment: Unless OP is dealing with a customized DNS or localhost then I would imagine the TLD is guaranteed for public-facing websites so you do not need to care about what it is but rather retrieve the second to last string when splitting by period.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree. It is so trivial that the answer is probably more useful if kept more generic.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dart but a one-liner could be `uri.host.split('.')[uri.host.split('.').length - 2]`

Comment: **Warning:** `Uri#host` doesn't actually work if the protocol isn't there. `Uri.parse('www.wikipedia.org/').host` is `""`.